# How to get an insert-text-button 'action property accessing a dynamically-bound buffer-local variable

Tags: elisp, text-properties, programming, buffer-local, lexical-scoping

In [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud) I have a text button that needs access to a dynamically-bound buffer-local variable.

The situation occurs like this. Inside one buffer that has the buffer local variable, there is a command that creates another "Describe" buffer with the value of that complex `defstruct` variable formatted nicely using org mode.

But inside that "Describe" buffer I would like to have a button that calls `describe-variable` on the variable, but have that use the value from its original buffer location, not the value in the describe buffer.

Currently I have inside `insert-text-button` an action property like this:

`'action '(lambda(button) (describe-variable 'realgud-cmdbuf-info))`

However this gives picks up the wrong buffer-local value. I can't change the above say to:

`'action '(lambda(button) (with-current-buffer buffer (describe-variable 'realgud-cmdbuf-info)))`

because of the quote in front of the lambda, and because `with-current-buffer` is a macro. Changing that to start `list('lambda(button) would be cumbersome if I could figure it out.

Probably I need to use some macro here, but that also is beyond my comprehension.

Help?

`

Comment: `` `(lambda (button) (with-current-buffer ',buffer (describe-variable 'readgud-cmdbuf-info)))``.

Comment: @Drew Sorry for the delayed reply. When I try that I get "save-current-buffer: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\, buffer)"

Comment: What I wrote should not be quoted. Remove the outer two backquotes from each end. There needs to be a single backquote in front of this: (lambda (button) (with-current-buffer ',buffer (describe-variable 'realgud-cmdbuf-info))). Of course, this must be done in a context where `buffer` is defined.

Comment: I had removed the outer two quotes when I tried this initially as I figured that was a typesetting artefact. So unsurprisingly, I get the same error message: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\, buffer). I am getting this when the lambda is called and the body executed, not when it is defined.

Comment: Is the single quote before buffer wanted? Shouldn't it read

    `(lambda (button) (with-current-buffer ,buffer (describe-variable 'readgud-cmdbuf-info)))

Comment: @theldoria You are correct that the single quote should be removed. However when I do that I get an error `Lisp error: (void-function \,)  (\, buffer)`. What works is zk_phi's solution where I set the buffer as a property and then get the property inside the action.

Comment: Assuming `buffer` is bound in this scope, all you have to do is remove the quote before `lambda` and enable `lexical-binding` in the .el file.  Alternatively use a backquote `\`` and then splice it in with `,` as suggested.  What ever you do don't single-quote `lambda`s, unless you want it to be treated as constant data, e.g. by the compiler.

Comment: @politza I just tried what I think you suggested I couldn't get it to work using `lexical-let` instead of `let`. The current code with the corrections given in zk_phi's answer is at  https://github.com/realgud/realgud/blob/master/realgud/common/buffer/command.el#L181-L184 . If you'd like to change that according to your suggestion and post it, that would be great.

Comment: Did so. BTW use `when` if you have only one branch (instead of `if`). And some people might look down on you for segregating your parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, that code (project started started in 2009) probably pre-dates the inclusion of `when`.  And yes, I know the parenthesis style is nonconventional. It's rational and I've found it more practical for the same reason that in other languages people put closers like `}` and `end` on new lines rather than add them at the end as their corresponding grammars allow. I've never been a fan of the style Nazi's "everyone do it my way because I've dictated that and think it looks nicer that way".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add not only `action` but any other attributes to a text-button, that can be referred later with `button-get` function. So saving the (reference to the) current buffer, together with `action`, seems a good idea here.

```
(insert-text-button
     "realgud-cmdbuf-info"
     'buffer buffer
     'action (lambda (b)
           (with-current-buffer (button-get b 'buffer)
             (describe-variable 'realgud-cmdbuf-info)))
```

Another solution is to enable `lexical-binding` in your script, that simply disables dynamic-binding.

Comment: Thanks - this works. However so that others may benefit it would be great to get a more detailed explanation of what's going on and how this addresses the problem. This was explicitly mentioned in the bounty.

If you can do that great. If not, I think I understand what's going on and when I get a chance I may try add more of an explanation. Also, at some point I'll revise the question to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Edited the answer. You can put any attributes to a button and `'buffer` is not a special-case.

Answer (score 1):

Start your file with

```el
;; Copyright (C) 2015-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

Now you're able to use closures in your Lisp code, e.g.

```el
(let ((x 0))
  (lambda () (setq x (1+ x))))
```

will create a count function.  The same applies to your anonymous function, it will close over it's lexical environment, i.e. it knows about the variable buffer.

```el
(insert-text-button
 "realgud-cmdbuf-info"
 'action (lambda (_button) ;; underscore makes compiler happy
           (describe-variable 'realgud-cmdbuf-info buffer))
 'help-echo "mouse-2: help-on-variable")
```

In rare circumstances, enabling `lexical-binding` can break your code, but only if you did something stupid to begin with. For example accessing local variables from a function up the call-stack.  And of course this won't work, if you're programming for ancient Emacs (I believe it was introduced in 24.1).

Comment: lexical binding was introduced in 24.1 (see NEWS.24 - `C-2 C-4 <f1> n`). The `'buffer buffer` should be redundant if you do it this way.

Comment: Unless he's using it someplace else, tough it doesn't look that way.